# How opacify background of header with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to opacify the background color of my navbar during the scroll. 
My Navbar is in the Header Div.

Actually, When I scroll my navbar is mixed with the content and I can't read anything.

I tried a lot of tutorials but my knowledge is poor in javascript and nothing works.

I just want the background header is opacity 0 when we are on the top of the page and become 0.7 when we scroll.

Thanks for your help.

```js
/*sticky_navbar*/

window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("header");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}


$(window).scroll(function() {
  var threshold = 200; // number of pixels before bottom of page that you want to start fading
  var op = (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop()) / threshold;
  if (op <= 0) {
    $("#header").hide();
  } else {
    $("#header").show();
  }
  $("#header").css("opacity", op);
});
```

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: rgba(139, 139, 157, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar {}

#Title {
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.menu:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.menu:nth-child(2) {
  order: 4;
}

.menu:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

.menu:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}

.menu:nth-child(5) {
  order: 5;
}

IMG.background {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60%;
}

#navbar a {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background: rgba(217, 78, 68, 0.5);
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: #FFF
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="navbar">
  <div id="Title">
    <a href="Accueil"><img src="IMAGES/PNG/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="menu"> <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Blog</a></div>
    <div class="menu"> <a href="blog">Contact</a></div>
    <div class="menu"> <a href="blog">L'électrophotonique</a></div>
    <div class="menu"> <a href="blog">Qui sommes nous?</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet was missing jQuery, so I added it for you. I presume this was just an oversight in the question and not the actual cause of your issue

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Scroll events based functions can be very greedy when not optimized, I'd advise you to use a lib such as the excellent scrollmagic http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: And you really want to check out debounce if you dont want to brick the browser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with what Mattia said, I have created a pen. I hope this helps.

I also added a css transition so it fades, but that was just a matter of personal preference. You can definitely remove that if you like.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/punsammy/pen/EeQyXP)

The changes are as follows: 
css

```
   #header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      background: rgba(139, 139, 157, 0);
        -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
      transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
      z-index: 2;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

#header.isSticky {
  background: rgb(139, 139, 157, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){// checks vertical position of scroll bar 
var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
// when user refreshes psge
if (scrollY > 0) {
  // if it is anywhere but the top change opacity by adding class .isSticky
  $('#header').addClass('isSticky');
} else {
  $('#header').removeClass('isSticky');
}


$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  // while uesr scrolls check the scrollTop position
  var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scrollY > 0) {
   $('#header').addClass('isSticky');
  } else {
   $('#header').removeClass('isSticky');
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle a class (`.isSticky` for example) with js on scroll by checking the element offset top.

```
#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: rgba(139, 139, 157, 0);
  z-index: 2;
}

#header.isSticky {
  background: rgba(139, 139, 157, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: I had  isSticky on my header class and the css style for  header.isSticky. 
Do have I something to do on the javascript file ?

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. I have in my ".js" to check the position of the header: If it's on the top so the style is   'background: rgba(139, 139, 157, 0);' and if not it's   'background: rgba(139, 139, 157, 0.7); '
That's right ?

Comment: Yes. You can check the offset top, or the scroll position (if is > 0 the user is scrolling)